# Cannot destroy youtube embedded video player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plyr

I am not able to destroy embedded youtube video on plyr player. `player.destroy()` method is called without any error but it does not destroy the player.

For this reason when I try to open another embedded video, it just loads the previous embedded video.

When I checked `isEmbed` property of the player it returns `false`. It should be `true` as I am playing youtube video.

I am using react js.

```
let video = document.getElementById('player-embed');

var youtubeEmbedId = extractYoutubeEmbedId(options.source.src)
window.player = new Plyr(video, defaultOptions);

useEffect(() => {

    return () => {
        window.player.destroy();
        if (window.hls) {
            window.destroyHLS();
        }
    }
}, [])

return (
    <div id="player-embed" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id={youtubeEmbedId}/>
);
```

I found [this](https://codepen.io/2braincells2go/pen/rKZRGq) codepen example for `plyr` youtube video example and it is working as expected. `isEmbed` property returns true and `player.destroy()` method indeed destroy the player. Don't know why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `window.player = new Plyr()` is called everytime your react component is rerendered, therefore you keep creating new Plyr instances. Try moving Plyr initialization to useState like `const [player] = useState(new Plyr())` and then assign it to window in `useEffect` so it would get called only once.

It still might have some bugs so you would be better off using Plyr official package for react https://github.com/chintan9/plyr-react

Comment: It should actually be `const [player] = useState(() => new Plyr())`, because your solution will still run `newPlayer`. And probably `useRef` instead of useState